# Django links and is_secure()

Tags: python, django, https, ssl

I am in the process of adding ssl to a django app and am running into some problems with my links redirecting from https to http.

Eventually I will have nginx redirect all http requests to https, but for now I am allowing both.

So if you go to https://www.mysite.com all is well. However, clicking on the "About link": href='/about' redirects you to http://www.mysite.com/about.

About is a super basic (static) page. Here's the entry in urls.py:

```
(r'^about/$', 'search.views.about'),
```

And here's the view function:

```
def about(request):
    return render_to_response('search/about.html')
```

Shouldn't django direct my users to https://www.mysite.com/about/ ? I believe this has something to do with the request.is_secure() method. Which always returns false for me. I have read that I need to set the os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on" for it to return true. How can I go about doing this? Is there something else I need to do? Should I just hardcode https into all my links?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: request.is_secure() won't help. Via this you can distinct between a secure and an uinsecure request in a view for example. Further django does not really care about https or http, its web server related. So you'll will have to configure your webserver to redirect requests on port 80 to requests on port 443 for example. There should be a good finding on google about this.

Comment: Here's the code i'm using to redirect http traffic to https in nginx. Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: if ($http_x_forwarded_port != 443) { rewrite ^ https://$http_host/; }

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the nginx code I was using was screwing everything up. Instead of:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_port != 443) { rewrite ^ https://$http_host/; }
```

use:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_port != 443) { rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
```

to do the redirection. As the first one drops all everything but the host.